# Composition of multi complex gaussian normal distribution

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

1. assume $w_0$, $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$ are circular symmetric complex Gaussian distributions, and the composite of 
   $$
   h = e^{j\theta_0}w_0 + e^{j\theta_3}w_3 - e^{j\theta_1}w_1 -e^{j\theta_2}w_2
   $$

   so what's the distribution of $h$ and $|h|$ given that the $\theta_i$ is determinate random variable, for example : $\theta_0+\theta_3 = \theta_1 + \theta_2$ ?
2. given
   $$
   w = w_0w_3 - w_1w_2
   $$ 
   what's the distribution of $w$ and $|w|$?
3. given 
   $$
   h = Ae^{j(a_1+b_1)} + Ae^{j(a_2+b_2)} - Ae^{j(a_2+b_1)} -Ae^{j(a_1+b_2)}
   $$
   if $a_i\sim \mathcal{U}(0,2\pi)$, $b_i\sim \mathcal{U}(0,2\pi)$, and A is a Rayleigh distribution Amplitude. can the probability distribution of $h$ and $|h|$ be calculated?

Thanks in advance! any hint and suggestion is helpful!

Best Regards!